# what “inline __attribute__((always_inline))” means in the function?

Tags: c, gcc

I have found the following function definition :

```
static inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int fn(const char *s)
{
  return (!s || (*s == '\0'));
}
```

And I want to know the meaning of `inline __attribute__((always_inline))`?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The often referenced `gcc` documentation for `always_inline` is incomplete.

`always_inline` attribute makes `gcc` compiler:

- Ignore `-fno-inline` (this is what the documentation says).
- Ignore **the inlining limits** hence inlining the function regardless. It also inlines functions with `alloca` calls, which `inline` keyword never does.
- Not produce an external definition of a function with external linkage if marked with `always_inline`.

The source of the above information is gcc source code, and, hence, is subject to change with no warning.

An interesting bechmark: [`always_inline`
performance](https://indico.cern.ch/event/386232/sessions/159923/attachments/771039/1057534/always_inline_performance.pdf).

Comment: icc also apply it now

Answer (score 25):

It forces the compiler to inline the function even if optimizations are disabled. Check [this documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) for more information.