# What's the difference between inline and __attribute__ inline?

Tags: c++

One can define an `inline` function using the `inline` keyword as it is shown in what follows:

```
inline void myFunc1() {
  cout << "FUNC1" << endl;
}
```

My question is, what is the difference between the aforementioned definition and the one that follows:

```
__attribute__((always_inline)) void myFunc2() {
  cout << "FUNC2" << endl;
}
```

Comment: For starters, one is language-standard supported, the other implementation-specific. The former example will compile with any standard-conformant C++ compiler that has put `cout` and `endl` in the global namespace. The latter will work only on implementations that support `__attribute__` (ex: MSVC++ does *not*; last I checked, anyway, whilst gcc and clang do).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what “inline \_\_attribute\_\_((always\_inline))” means in the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767523/what-inline-attribute-always-inline-means-in-the-function)  See Also: [inline specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)