# ARM-GCC - Force Inline of all calls made within a function

Tags: gcc, arm

currently i am working on a self-update feature for an embedded bootloader on an ARM M4F.

**What i have done:**

I have a wrapper function executed from flash, which does some preperation and then calls the function which executes the self update - this is executed from RAM. At the end of the self-update i do a reset, to not use any "old code".

All working nice and fine.

**What the problem is:**

I would like to use functions from other .c/.h files within the function stored RAM.
Now, these are stored in FLASH - so can not be used during the self-update.

I have full controll over these functions (Can change signature and implementation, but would like not to)

**My Question is:**

Is there an arm-gcc attribute/way to inform the compiler, that all calls within the RAM-Function **have** (How to check in an automated way if they are inlined at compile time?) to be inlined?

The functions called should be executed from flash when used somewhere else. So inline only in this single case.

Thank you!

Comment: put all update functions into separate section and load a whole section. So you would not depend on inlining.

Comment: create as a separate binary that is linked for ram, copy and run if needed.

Comment: There is no option.  You can use [always inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767523/what-inline-attribute-always-inline-means-in-the-function) as a define which is switched on for code to program flash.  Also, the `NOCROSSREFS_TO()` linker function can be used to check that the flash programming code does not inadvertently have a reference to flash.  For instance, some error path that is not commonly tested.

Comment: @artlessnoise Does 'flatten' not work on ARM?

Comment: Flatten may work now and it is more likely to work in the future.  Really the OPs issue is that he has a DAG call structure and wants to make it a tree.  The only way to do this is to duplicate entries.  It is really a mis-use of inline; flatten could work, but may not have existed at the time of this question.  Also, it could increase the ram footprint, so it may not be optimal for this use case.